# Why I can t get my this.refs.children elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m trying to get the element of a ref in React, but my console.log returns undefined.

here a visual_log of the situation:

[image: here we can see the HTML collection have well some element,but when call then, there is a problem: the console returns undefined]

*In this image we can see that in a first time, the HTML collection have well some element, but when I m trying to call the arrayElement then, there is a problem: the console returns undefined*

Here my code:

```
let sliderContainer= this.refs.sliderContainer
console.log("sliderContainer: ", sliderContainer) // return reference element with all property inside
console.log("sliderContainer.childNodes: ", sliderContainer.childNodes,sliderContainer.children ) // return NodeList, HTMLCollection.... length 4
console.log("sliderContainer.childNodes[0]: ", sliderContainer.childNodes[0], sliderContainer.children[0) // return undefined, undefined
```

How it is possible since my console display me in the first log all the div elements inside my refereed component?

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's `HTMLCollection`, it works like an array, so you can access to elements by index `collection[index]`. For more information you can see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Comment: Additionally, you can use `Array.from` to convert it to a standard JS array.

Comment: @odensc sure, if it's necessary.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is what I m doing, but it returns me undefined, I have realized a concrete log to help you appreciate the situation

Comment: @Webwoman it's really strange as in your code snippet `sliderContainer.childNodes` returns undefined, but in visual log it returns NodeList. What is the correct?

Comment: oups, typo of my part, is the visual the good, I correct that :)

Comment: @Webwoman it's anyways really strange, have you tried use `item(index)` function for getting item by index from NodeList and HTMLCollection ?

Comment: okay it returns me null, here my code:    `console.log("sliderContainer.childNodes.item(0): ", sliderContainer.childNodes.item(0))
    console.log("sliderContainer.children.item(0): ", sliderContainer.children.item(0))`

Comment: @Webwoman can you have some typos in your code? looks like you have different `sliderContainer` objects each time...

Comment: I will get an eye on my code, maybe it can be some interaction with other files eventually